# String to timestamp in Postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, timestamp

## Problem

How do you convert a string to a timestamp?

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) and all answers that I have found show how to convert at string column to timestamp with the to_timestamp function, but this apparently does not work for a single string.

## What I have tried

```
to_timestamp('2019-09-20 13:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

Cast('2019-09-20 13:59' as timestamp)
```

## What I want to do

I want to add a column to a table with this date as a repeated value.

```
-- Creating timestamp column
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD creation_date timestamp

-- Repeating timestamp 
UPDATE my_table  SET creation_date = TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-20 13:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The code you have shown will work just fine: https://rextester.com/GQC96126

Comment: Your code works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8ad0f5bbaf6df7c104c7b31fac86cd4e

Comment: The problem was that the code fails unless you write 'select' in front of it apparently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try below - change your format mask from `'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'` to `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0157432568759625b12c00c8decc7b02)**

```
select to_timestamp('2019-09-20 13:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Oh, so the error message is because, you can not just run it without select?

Comment: Thanks! I had a case where a `date` column was wrongly typed TEXT with ISO 8061 values, I did this: `to_timestamp(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')`.